# Speed up Save to PDF Excel 2016 VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pdf-generation

I'm trying to figure out if there is a quicker way in my program to save to pdf. When I run the following code, it takes about 25 seconds for it to save each pdf file I have. I have narrowed the bottleneck to the save to pdf code by stepping through the code. I tried turning the automatic calculation to manual but that didn't help.

Basically, what this script is doing is checking how many loan borrowers there are (customer packages may be less than but will never be more than 4), then populating some data and then printing a some worksheets.

Here is my code:

```
`customerpackages = 0

For counter = 1 To 19
    If Sheets("Loan Data").Cells(2, counter) <> "" Then
    customerpackages = customerpackages + 1
    counter = counter + 6
    End If
Next counter

For j = 1 To (customerpackages * 2)
    Sheets("Certification").Range("G43").Value = ssn_array(j - 1)
    Sheets("Certification").Range("G46").Value = ssn_array(j)
    Sheets("Anti-steering").Cells(3, 1).Value = borrower_array(j - 1)
    Sheets("Anti-steering").Cells(4, 1).Value = borrower_array(j)
    If borrower_array(j) = " " Then
        Sheets("Rate Lock").Cells(10, 1).Value = "NAME : " & borrower_array(j - 1)
    Else
        Sheets("Rate Lock").Cells(10, 1).Value = "NAME : " & borrower_array(j - 1) & " and" & borrower_array(j)
    End If
    Worksheets(common_disclosures).Select
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "C:\users\" & environ_user & "\desktop\" & borrower_array(j - 1) & " 
    disclosures.pdf" _
    , Quality:=xlQualityMinimum, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
    j = j + 1
Next j`
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It looks fairly clean code to me (except could not clearly get counter +.6 stuff). May wait for more experienced expert's to answer or comment.

Comment: Is it taking an excessive amount of time on any specific line? If it's on `ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat` the that's the time it takes to export.

Comment: Yes. That’s what I’m trying to figure out. How do I speed up the export time?

Comment: In my export file from which I’m importing data into this excel file the borrower names are every 6 columns, hence + 6